# C++17 doesn't allow special syntax for nested namespaces, despite what I've read

Tags: c++, namespaces

The title says it all, I think. And yes, I read a lot of other posts. Some even said they got it to work.

The thing is, bad practice aside, I would like to be able to (not saying I'll use it!!!) write something like:

```
namespace Ns1::Ns2::Ns3 {
    class C { };
}
```

I read that C++17 would support it, but I keep getting compiler errors that say something about a qualified name was expected. I know what that means, but I don't know why some people get it to work and I don't.

I also read somewhere that you have to turn on a 'switch' in Visual Studio 2017 for this syntax to be accepted, but I haven't been able to find this so called 'switch'.

So, is it a fact that this syntax is simply not supported? Please don't tell me stuff like 'even if it were, you'd better stay away from it' -- I just want to know if it's possible.

Thank you so much in advance, looking forward to your replies :-) Have a nice day all!

Comment: Just because it's in C++17 doesn't mean that your compiler has implemented a particular feature, yet.

Comment: try digging in release notes, however it's possible it's not implemented yet

Comment: Remember `C++17` isn't a standard yet and compilers can only implement so much with a moving target.

Comment: ATM Visual Studio 2017 has some c++17 features impletented if you enable an C++ language standard to latest in project Settings > C/C++ > Language > C++ Language standard. It is still missing majority of new features like f.e. if constexpr.

Comment: You can look up [Visual C++ conformance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance) online. A [recent blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/03/07/c-standards-conformance-from-microsoft/) might be of interest.

Comment: I apologize for not responding to your replies until now. But I've read them all, and they are all very helpful and very much appreciated. Thank you very much to all of you!